# Why we are calling static method overriding as method hiding

Tags: java

```
class Parent {
    public static void m1() {
        System.out.println("Parent");
    }
}

class Child extends Parent {
    public static void m1() {
        System.out.println("Child");
    }
}
```

This is the above code sample.

Please explain according to this.

Comment: It's not overriding because there is no dynamic dispatch. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch

Comment: `static` methods cannot be overriden.

Comment: Just fyi - There 2 main forms of dispatch, `static` and `dynamic`. You can read more about there [here](https://medium.com/ingeniouslysimple/static-and-dynamic-dispatch-324d3dc890a3) and [here](https://lukasatkinson.de/2016/dynamic-vs-static-dispatch/)

Answer (score 1):

Overriding a method means that the method call is [dynamically dispatched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_dispatch) based on the type of the object at runtime:

```java
>>> class A { int foo() { return 1; } }
>>> class B extends A { int foo() { return 2; } }
>>> A a = new B();
>>> a.foo()
2
>>> ((B) a).foo()
2
>>> B b = new B();
>>> b.foo()
2
>>> ((A) b).foo()
2
```

This doesn't happen if the method is static; a static method is not called on an object, it is called on a class, and you normally write the class name instead of using an object to call it:

```java
>>> class A { static int bar() { return 1; } }
>>> A.bar()
1
```

That said, you *can* write a static method call where the left hand side is an object instead of the class name, but a static method call is dispatched based on the compile-time type of that expression, not the object's type at runtime:

```java
>>> class B extends A { static int bar() { return 2; } }
>>> A a = new B();
>>> a.bar()
1
>>> ((B) a).bar()
2
>>> B b = new B();
>>> b.bar()
2
>>> ((A) b).bar()
1
```

So this not overriding and it does not have the behaviour of overriding.

Comment: In fact, you should even get a compiler warning (at least in Eclipse) when you call a static method on an object instead of a class.